# Обработка кликов после изменения капчи

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Скрипт обновления капчи:

```
$(function() { // обновление капчи без перезагрузки
    $("img#capt_reg").click(function() {
        $("div#captcha").html("<img width='90' height='25' id='capt_reg' src='captcha.php?anti_cache=" + Math.random() + "' style='margin-left: 28px; margin-bottom: -6px;\' > ");
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="captcha" > 
    <img width="90" height="25" id="capt_reg" src="captcha.php?timestamp=<?php echo mktime();?>" style="margin-left: 28px; margin-bottom: -6px;" >
</div>
```

После загрузки страницы капчу по нажатию на картинку можно обновить только 1 раз.

Но если это событие повести на стороннюю картинку, то тогда капча обновляется сколько угодно раз.

Как сделать так, чтобы картинка капчи обновляла саму капчу постоянно, а не один раз?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как `<img id="capt_reg">` каждый раз создаётся заново, то можно использовать [delegated event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

```js
$(function() {
    var $captcha = $('#captcha');
    $captcha.on('click', '#capt_reg', function () {
        $captcha.html("<img width='90' height='25' id='capt_reg' src='captcha.php?anti_cache=" + Math.random() + "' style='margin-left: 28px; margin-bottom: -6px;\' > ");
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="captcha" > 
    <img width="90" height="25" id="capt_reg" src="captcha.php?timestamp=123" style="margin-left: 28px; margin-bottom: -6px;" />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Однако в данном конкретном случае разумнее просто менять `src` картинки:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#capt_reg').on('click', function() {
        this.src = 'captcha.php?anti_cache=' + Math.random();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="captcha" > 
    <img width="90" height="25" id="capt_reg" src="captcha.php?timestamp=123" style="margin-left: 28px; margin-bottom: -6px;" />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: да я уже нашел. ошибку. Спасибо ваш код помог. Благодарю вас

Comment: @Raaur на здоровье.

Answer (score 0):

Ну очевидно потому что обновив капчу, вы перезатерли объект к которому применили событие click. Вам надо ли заново вешать click на картинку, либо применять click к другому объекту, который остается неизменным. Например к

```
$("div#captcha")
```